Find project with chat API enabled
I created a PHP script that sends messages via chat API and it works perfect but I need to get more tokens.
It generates them using
https://chat.googleapis.com/v1/spaces/{chat-room}/messages?key=XXXX&tokenYYYY
I can't find in any of my projects the chat API enabled so I don't even know how I did this. How can this be? Is there any other API that can manage these requests?

Really simple. After a few hours lost.
There was never set as an API request. This was set from webhooks app inside chat not in google cloud. This was done years ago and had forgotten how. Solved
This is done through chat menu > Apps and integrations > webhooks > add webhook
You give it a name and get a url with key and token to add to your script.

Can you further elaborate on this solution so that other community members who will encounter the same issue can use this post as a reference?
